# The possibility of a symmetric difference in a torsion-free group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a torsion-free group  containing two elements $x$ and $y$ and a finite non-empty subset $B$ such that $B=xB \triangle yB$, where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference of two sets and $xB$ denotes the set $\{xb \;:\; b\in B\}$?

Edited May 29, 2015:

The question is equivalent to the following:

Is there a torsion-free group $G$ and elements $x,y\in G$ such that $1+x+y$ is a zero divisor in the group ring $\mathbb{F}_2[G]$, where $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field with $2$ elements?

Comment: It's not possible when the group is bi-orderable (e.g., abelian or even nilpotent, or free). Indeed, if $x_1B=x_2B\Delta x_3B$ then since $B$ is nonempty, we have $x_1,x_2,x_3$ pairwise distinct, and since this condition is symmetric in $x_1,x_2,x_3$, we can suppose $x_1<x_2<x_3$. Since $B$ is finite, it has a maximal element $b$, so that $x_3b$ belongs to neither $x_2B$ nor $x_1B$, contradicting the condition.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks. It is also easy to prove the non-existence of such torsion-free groups if they satisfy  unique product property. In the meanwhile, if such group exists the size of $B$ must be even.

Comment: My guess is that constructing such groups would require a small cancelation argument and some computer assistance in order to check that these (graphical?) small cancelation conditions are fulfulled (by prescribing $B$ to be of some given even large enough cardinal).

Comment: See above for an equivalent question